# How to set image from memory in android program?

Tags: android, image

In Android application..
My requirement is :--
I have a space of  120dp X 120dp size in my activity..
I want When I click that space it will shows options:--

1. phone memory
2. SD card

I can select any of them.from there I can select any image(only 1 at a time)..
After select it will set at the 120dp X 120dp size..

I have read `http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html` but I cant understand how I call the memory?? 1)Phone memory and 2)sdcard..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for load a bitmap:

```
ImageView imgInternal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgInternal);
ImageView imgExternal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgExternal);
String internal = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "img.png"; // For internal storage
String external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "img.png"; // For external storage
Bitmap bmpExternal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(external); // For external
Bitmap bmpInternal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(internal); // For internal
imgExternal.setImageBitmap(bmpExternal);
imgInternal.setImageBitmap(bmpInternal);
```

for external storage you should add this to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(external); 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(internal);
It is saying    "Duplicate local variable bmp"

Comment: You must choose one, internal o external, if you want use two memories you should change name of one Bitmap variable. I am goint to edit my answer.

Comment: But from one imageview i cant get the two options??? ph memory and sd card memory choose any one..

Comment: From one ImageView you can choose one option at time. You can load a external storage image or a internal storage image. But then, you can change and show in that ImageView other image (from external or internal)